# Spacy is_stop function(bug?)

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, stop-words, spacy

I am using the below code to check if a word is a stop word or not. As you can see below, if the try block fails, the IS_STOP function is throwing an error.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
try:
    print 0/0 #Raise and Exception 
except:
    print nlp.is_stop('is')`
```

I get the below error:

```
      5     print 0/0
      6 except:
----> 7     print spacy.load('en').is_stop('is')
AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'is_stop'  `
```

Comment: Works for me on python 3.4. Perhaps the error is python2-specific.

Comment: @DYZ, please don't change a question based on a assumption. Also the `python` tag has more visbility then `python-2.7`. If it would be a `2.7` problem, the tag should be added, not replaced. Also [see this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265845/2441442).

Comment: I don't think this is Python 2.7 specific, I'm finding I get this error thru pip Spacy, and not thru conda Spacy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process some text by 'calling' the `nlp` object as a function as explained [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/processing-text). You can then test for stop words on each token of the parsed sentence.
For example:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> sentence = nlp(u'this is a sample sentence') 
>>> sentence[1].is_stop
True
```

In case you want to test for stop words directly from the English vocabulary, use the following:

```
>>> nlp.vocab[u'is'].is_stop
True
```